# Hashing to form couples

Tags: java, hash, cluster-analysis

I'm working on my final project for master degree and I'm facing a problem. I have some clusters containing information like: user_id, latitude and longitude, array of hours in which the user is in that cluster, array of days of week in which the user is in that cluster etc... I should be able to find people who leave near clusters in the same time span and arrive to near clusters in the same time span. So, for example, I have a cluster representing my house that is near to another cluster representing another user's house. We both leave home at 7 a.m and we both go almost to the same place between 7 a.m and 8 a.m. I'd like to couple this two users.
I should be able to realize this in a fast way from the computational point of view. My professor told me that we could use hashing to do this. How could hashing be used to do so?
Maybe calculating hashing value of some values of the clusters and grouping those are similar?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think I should use HashMaps to make a key, value pair and work with those hashMaps. Am I right?

Comment: No, he probably meant locality sensitive hashing. Why don't you ask him for references to use?

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse. I'll ask him when we'll talk againg :) I think also that maybe he could have talked about using HashMaps to store some data e use them for searching.

Comment: However, I'm gonna read something about locality sensitive hashing . Thank you again :D